# Cat 5e in wall what cable to use to my pc?

Tags: ethernet, cat6, cat5e

I have an ethernet cable in the wall and it is cat 5e. If I use a Cat 6 from the wall to my PC, will it make it better than using a Cat 5e from the wall to my PC?

If it will make my performance better, then what is the best cable I can use?

Comment: Questions seeking hardware recommendations (best Ethernet cable) are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: Cat 6 will make no difference.

Comment: What research have you done regarding this subject?

Answer (score 1):

If your wall has Cat5e in it, then you cannot get above a Cat5e connection.  That being said, you can connect a Cat6 cable to it and it will still function properly.

That being said, depending on the length of the 5e run, the quality of the cabling, it is *possible* to get gigabit speeds if the ports support it.